# I'm trying to prevent default behavior when I hit enter but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have a input text to update a field in a database. When i hit enter on the keyboard I call a php page that does the update. Unfortunately, for company policies, I have to use IE. I have been told that the default behavior in IE of hitting enter is the submit of a form.

Now, this input text is not part of any form, so I don't know what could be possibly submitted.

This is the javascript behind it. What I'm doing wrong?

As you can see, after I set the parameters to send I alert the string with the parameter, and when I do that, the value I just changed takes the old value.

```
function submitData(id, tab, codProd, riga, R004) {
    document.querySelector("#" + id).onkeydown = function(event) {
        if(event.key == "Enter") { 
            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
            var esito = confirm("Sei sicuro di voler modificare il dato?"); 
            if(esito) {
                if('ActiveXObject' in window){
                    infoXmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                }else{
                    infoXmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                if(infoXmlHttp) {
                    try{
                        infoXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                if(this.responseText == 1) {
                                    document.getElementById(id).readOnly = true;
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                                else {
                                    document.getElementById(id).value = riga;
                                    document.getElementById(id).readOnly = true;
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        infoXmlHttp.open("POST", serverAddress, false);
                        infoXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        var val = $('#'+id).val();
                        var param = "codProd=" + codProd + "&tab=" + tab + "&key=" + id + "&value=" + val + "&R004=" + R004;
                        alert(param);
                        infoXmlHttp.send(param);
                    } catch(e) {
                        var log = "Error connecting to the server - submitData";
                        alert(log);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(id).value = riga;
            document.getElementById(id).readOnly = true;
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. All the stuff you do that isn't about preventing the form from submitting (i.e. all the Ajax) is irrelevant. A minimal amount of HTML is *not* irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using jQuery so here's what I tend to use to stop forms being submitted by pressing the enter key.

It should be placed inside a doc ready function

```
/* Prevent form from being submitted if a user presses enter whilst focused on an input field */
var inputs = $('input, textarea, select').not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]');
$(inputs).on('keypress', function(e) {
    return e.which !== 13;
});
```